# reverse proxy nginx to proxied nginx instance. with SSL and static, how?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have **nginx** & **webserver** that are working together on the same server and it's working flawlessly.

Now I need to move the webserver to another physical server (B or C)
[image]

it's was seem easy at first glance, but keeping SSL & static seem to make thing more difficult that it should be...

When evertyhing was on the same server (A)
I had this in the nginx config file (for the static)

```
location  /static/ {
    alias /somewhere/static/;
}
```

but it seem (TBC) that static command only point to local.

So it was advised (without more explanation of course)

To run a main **nginx** that act as the reverse proxy, and nginx instance on the proxied server (B,C)

sound logic, but I can't found any documentation that explain how link the Main the to proxied and have the SSL & static working...

(edit: of course If I could have the most of the config directive on (A) SSL etc.. that would be awesome.. )

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I spend a "little" time to figure it out. but I least I made it..

The best as always it's to start from scratch..

For those who look also the answer, on (A) you just handle the SSL and the proxy_pass to the peroxided and that all. and all the rest on the peroxided :)

I'm keeping on eye on this post, in case you need more info.

Cheers